# Table Comparison with NULL value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, compare

I'm looking for the best way to compare two tables and return the rows which contain differences between two tables.

//TABLE A

```
CREATE TABLE `mydb`.`a` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `color` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `animal` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `mydb`.`a` 
    (id,color,animal) 
VALUES 
    (1,"red",""),
    (2,"blue","cat"),
    (3,"green","dog");
    (4,"orange","fish");
```

//TABLE B

```
CREATE TABLE `mydb`.`b` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `color` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `animal` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `mydb`.`b` 
    (id,color,animal) 
VALUES 
    (1,"red",""),
    (2,"blue","cat"),
    (3,"green","bird");
    (4,"brown","fish");
```

The statement would return rows 3,4 of table B since `bird` and `brown` is different then `dog` and `orange`.

Comment: `AND IS NOT NULL` ??

Comment: @Dagon where should I insert?

Comment: What output are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @GordonLinoff to generate the differences, so if a user changes something on the xls then loads it in, it goes to a the table `facilities_update` then runs the above statement, now whats happening is even if their is a null (blank) value in the `facilities` table and in the `facilities_update` it will count that as a difference even though they aren't different, theyre both null.

Comment: @GordonLinoff so right now I made like 4 changes to the xls so it should only pull those 4 rows, but instead any row with a null value is being included in the results

Comment: @GordonLinoff to give you an example say I changed 4 `OrderNumbers` on the xls, uploaded it into `facilities_update` then run the compare... it should return only those 4 rows with the changed `OrderNumber`... Instead it returns those 4 rows and any row with a null value because for some reason the null value in the `facilities_update` table doesn't equal the null value in `facilities` table and therefore counts it as a difference, which I don't understand why, since NULL should equal NULL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NULL represent lack of information. It will never match to other values (including other NULLs). So, for example, while zero is equal zero:

```
SQL> select case when 0 = 0 then 'true' else 'false' end ;
case when 0 = 0 then 'true' else 'false' end
--------------------------------------------
true
```

NULL is **not** equal NULL:

```
SQL> select case when null = null then 'true' else 'false' end ;
case when null = null then 'true' else 'false' end
--------------------------------------------------
false
```

you will have to *convert* NULL to other values (for example zero) if you want to match them:

```
SQL> select case when ifnull(null, 0) = ifnull(null, 0) then 'true' else 'false' end ;
case when ifnull(null, 0) = ifnull(null, 0) then 'true' else 'false' end
------------------------------------------------------------------------
true
```

**EDIT**

Assuming you have:

```
mysql> select * from a;
+----+--------+--------+
| id | color  | animal |
+----+--------+--------+
|  1 | red    |        |
|  2 | blue   | cat    |
|  3 | green  | dog    |
|  4 | orange | fish   |
+----+--------+--------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from b;
+----+-------+--------+
| id | color | animal |
+----+-------+--------+
|  1 | red   |        |
|  2 | blue  | cat    |
|  3 | green | bird   |
|  4 | brown | fish   |
+----+-------+--------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I would use:

```
mysql> select b.* from b left outer join a on a.id = b.id and 
       a.animal = b.animal and a.color = b.color 
       where a.id is null and a.animal is null and a.color is null ;
+----+-------+--------+
| id | color | animal |
+----+-------+--------+
|  3 | green | bird   |
|  4 | brown | fish   |
+----+-------+--------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

to find rows in B with differences from th corresponding rows in A.
And:

```
mysql> select a.* from a left outer join b on a.id = b.id and 
       a.animal = b.animal and a.color = b.color 
       where b.id is null and b.animal is null and b.color is null ;
+----+--------+--------+
| id | color  | animal |
+----+--------+--------+
|  3 | green  | dog    |
|  4 | orange | fish   |
+----+--------+--------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

to find rows in A different from the corresponding rows in B.

Comment: Or, better still, `ISNULL(a) AND ISNULL(b)`.

Comment: I don't want to match them, I wan't to unmatch them... what I'm saying is that both tables contain a blank cell for that column/row but yet it says their values are different... even though they are both blank/empty. I only wan't the differences.

Comment: @JordanDavis: Yes, mauro explained that. By "blank/empty" you mean `NULL`, and `NULL` is not a value. It is the lack of a value. Equality is a comparison between values. One `NULL` does not _equal_ some other `NULL`, so this is completely expected behaviour. mauro further suggested alternative approaches to achieving your actual goal, as did I.

Comment: @mauro so your saying run a statement before to convert all empty values in both tables to (0's|NULL|false) so that it has an actual value and then run the statement?

Comment: @JordanDavis you can change the base table to replace NULLs with other values (assuming you can...) or extract NULLs and "replace" them on the flight while running the SELECT (ifnull() or, better, isnull() as suggested by LightnessRacesinOrbit). What is important for you to understand is that NULL means *unknown* and *unknown* is **not** equal to *unknown*

Comment: @mauro so they come in from the xls blank... I could run a statement before or could you show me what you mean by inserting isnull() on flight as per my statement, like where would I insert that.

Comment: @JordanDavis replacing blank cells with a different value to represent NULLs while loading if probably faster. If you want us to provide help with changing your SQL please post DDL, sample data, current SQL output and desired result

Comment: You can do it with any table doesn't have to be my specific columns make two tables (a) and (b) and make them both have a blank column, and then change the value of another. (a.myFirstColumn = cat and b.myFirstColumn = dog) then add (a.myBlankColumn = ''" and b.myBlankColumn = "") and I only want to pull the cat/dog difference not the blank/blank column difference

Comment: @JordanDavis there were small typos in your DDL/DML statements. I was not able to just cut&paste them. Answer updated. **PS** I'd suggest to use explicit NULL when you want to insert NULLs rather than empty strings...

Comment: @mauro changed the database to whatever you want its not hard... like I said they don't come in as explicit NULL from the xls, they are empty strings

Comment: @mauro awesome! Thank you